# How can if else be replaced with Optional.orElse in GZIPWrapper?

Tags: java, servlets

Hello everyone working with gzip, I was faced with a question. I have a GzipWrapper and there is a lot of if else, is it possible to do something like that with Optional.orElse? With simple Optional examples, I sorted it out, but I don’t quite understand how to do this in a wrapper. An example on one of the methods will suffice) Thanks in advance)

MyWrapper:

```
public class GZIPFilterResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper implements Closeable {

    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private GZIPFilterResponseStream gzipStream;
    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;

    public GZIPFilterResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        super(response);
        response.addHeader(CONTENT_ENCODING, GZIP);
        gzipStream = new GZIPFilterResponseStream(response.getOutputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (nonNull(printWriter)) {
            printWriter.flush();
        }
        if (nonNull(outputStream)) {
            outputStream.flush();
        }
        super.flushBuffer();
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        if (nonNull(printWriter)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(GZIP_CANNOT_WRITE);
        }
        if (isNull(outputStream)) {
            outputStream = gzipStream;
        }
        return outputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        if (nonNull(outputStream)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(GZIP_WRITER_ALREADY_HAS_CALLING);
        }
        if (isNull(printWriter)) {
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(gzipStream, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()));
        }
        return printWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (nonNull(printWriter)) {
            printWriter.close();
        }
        if (nonNull(outputStream)) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Optional` is not a replacement for conditional logic.

`Optional` was added so that APIs had a *consistent way* of declaring that a method returns a value that may or may not be present, without returning null. Returning `null` is vulnerable to exceptions, and there is no easy way to know whether to expect `null` without reading the documentation. `Optional` makes this contract explicit.

So while it may be *possible* to replace your conditional logic with `Optional`s, that would be unlikely to make your code any better or any easier to read.

---

Here's one example just to satisfy your curiosity:

```
if (nonNull(printWriter)) {
    printWriter.flush();
}
```

becomes

```
Optional.ofNullable(printWriter).ifPresent(PrintWriter::flush);
```

Comment: Ok, I get it,  but I'm just wondering how it will look.) Just to see the difference.

Comment: @Mefisto_Fell Ah, well allow me to save you some time: it will look bad.

Comment: @Mefisto_Fell I've given you one example of a like-for-like replacement which you could make. This one isn't particularly bad, but it's not any better than the alternative either